# django how to make python script executed from bash write stdout to file?

Tags: python, django, bash

I am using Django and I am getting a ton of errors and deprecation warning when I run tests and unsilence the warnings with the command...

```
python -Wall manage.py test
```

In regular bash I would usually do soemthing like this...

```
command > log.log
```

but that is not working, or it is only writing a very small fraction of the output to a file. I could write a python script, but the output is likely soming from all over the Django frameword and I would really rather just get this output into a file.

I have also tried the `-u` option on the python comand and that did not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're seeing errors written to stdout and stderr both, then you'll want to redirect both of them:

```
 python -Wall manage.py test >log.log 2>&1
```

There's (much) more here about shell redirection: [In the shell, what does " 2>&1 " mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean)

Comment: ahhh ok. I knew what that meant but it didn't click that is what was hapenning